# EQU directive in GAS assembly

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler

Why does `.equ` directive not work in gas in this way:

```
.equ Mark64, 8(%rsi)
```

while it works in this (note: `.text` section, where `Mark32` is located, is set to r/w in this case):

```
Mark32 EQU DWORD PTR [ESI + 4]
```

How can i make `Mark64` work in GAS (`.set` also doesn't work)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use preprocessed assembly and `#define`. Alternatively, only define the offset, such as `.equ Mark64, 8` then you can do `movl Mark64(%rsp), %eax` for example.

Comment: @fuz have you? It doesn't work, because `.equ` defines a symbol, not a text replacement and `8(%rsp)` is not a valid value for a symbol.

Comment: @fuz, yes, i've tried. comma is a typo error here. still doesn't work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Data section:

```
MarksTable:
    .quad Mark64_1
    .quad Mark64_2
    .quad Mark64_3
```

where `Mark64_x` is just a label in code section.

And then I've just placed my `MarksTable` into reg:

```
movq MarksTable, %rsi
```

After all I could access `Mark64_2` for instance from `rsi` like this:

```
callq   *0x8(%rsi)
```

Comment: `movq MarksTable, %rsi` is a load of the first element.  Use `lea MarksTable(%rip), %rsi`, or `mov $MarksTable, %esi`.  Or better, `call *8+MarksTable(%rip)`.

Answer (score 2):

In some assembly languages (e.g. MASM) `equ` is a text substitution.

But in GAS, `.equ` is a numeric constant, like `foo = 3` in MASM.  For text substitutions, use the C preprocessor `#define Mark64 8(%rsi)`.  Name your file `foo.S` so gcc will run it through CPP before assembling.

`equ` in NASM also defines a numeric assemble-time constant, and uses `%define` for text substitutions.

---

And BTW, defining Mark64 to `8(%rsi)` seems like a bad / confusing idea.  People don't expect something that looks like a symbol name to actually contain a register reference.  Defining the numeric magic constant `8` to a meaningful name could be good, though.